# Why my code is blocking

Tags: node.js

Hi I'm learning asynchronous functions in node.js but I don't understand why my code is blocking even if I use the callback.
This is my code.

```
function isPerfectNumber(num, callback) {
var sum = 0;

for( var i = 1; i<=(num/2); i++ )
    if( num%i == 0 ) {
        sum += i;
    }
    if( sum == num ) {
        callback(num);
    }
}

exports.getNPerfectNumbers = function(n) {
var count = 0;
var i = 1;
while(count<n) {
    isPerfectNumber(i, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        count++;
    });
    i++;
}
}
```

Comment: callbacks don't magically make synchronous code asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how asynchronous processing works with JavaScript:**

JavaScript will execute all instructions on its current stack immediately. Some of those instructions may put code onto JavaScript's [event loop](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/) (for example, the `setTimeout` function). As soon as JavaScript finishes executing all of its instructions on the current stack then it checks the event loop to see if anything is waiting to execute.

Read up about the [event loop](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/) and you'll probably be able to answer your own question.

**Why Callbacks Can Be Synchronous:**

As @KevinB stated, just because you use a callback does not mean that it executes asynchronously. JavaScript is a flexible language that allows you to write code [imperatively or declaratively](https://tylermcginnis.com/imperative-vs-declarative-programming/) (allowing the use of the [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) paradigm) and that is due to JavaScript functions being first class objects.